# Fetching collection inside a subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Supposing we have two tables, linked by a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUIDType, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    courses = db.relationship('Course',
                              secondary=student_courses,
                              backref=db.backref('students'))


class Course(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(UUIDType, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

I am trying to query the name of the students with the names of the courses s/he is subscribed to using a subquery, but it only shows the name of the first matching course (not all of them). In other words, I would like to retrieve `(student_id, student_name, [list of course_names])`.

```
sq = db.session.query(Student.id.label('student_id'),
                      Course.id.label('course_id'),
                      Course.name.label('course_name')) \
               .join(Student.courses) \
               .group_by(Student.id, Course.id).subquery('pattern_links_sq')

db.session.query(Student.id, Student.name, sq.c.course_name) \
          .join(Student.courses)
          .filter(Student.id == sq.c.student_id).all()
```

Comment: which database you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) function in PostgreSQL

```
from sqlalchemy import func

db.session.query(Student.id, Student.name, func.array_agg(Course.name))\
          .join(Student.courses)\
          .group_by(Student.id)\
          .all()
```